# AngularJs. Is it possible to deselect HTML “radio” input by click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I have radio inputs and want to ucheck state by click on radio if current radio is checked.

This code:

```
<input type="radio" id="average_0" name="average" ng-model="checked" ng-change="false" value="500" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<input type="radio" id="average_1" name="average" ng-model="checked" ng-change="false" value="1000" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
<input type="radio" id="average_2" name="average" ng-model="checked" ng-change="false" value="1500" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

Not working.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zoomer/8s4m2e5e/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Radio buttons can be selected only one at a time and cannot be unchecked by the user once they are checked (unless you do programmatically). So if you want to uncheck it when it is currently selected, you can do this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="500" ng-click="uncheck($event)" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="1000" ng-click="uncheck($event)" />
<input type="radio" ng-model="checked" value="1500" ng-click="uncheck($event)" />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.uncheck = function (event) {
    if ($scope.checked == event.target.value)
        $scope.checked = false
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8s4m2e5e/3/

NOTE: If you really want to choose one or none from many options, you may opt for a `<select>`

Comment: Oh, thanks! I know theory, but i dont know how made this in Angular.

Comment: Ok, i acept it. Thanks again, current version of answer is very good for me.

Comment: Don't you mean radio buttons in the answers first sentence?

Comment: This does not work in Angular 1.3 anymore.

In 1.3, the checked value is set to "xyz" before the click event is fired.

Comment: how to uncheck radio buttons programatically without jQuery (and without direct user interaction)?

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution that works on Angular 1.3+ is:

Template

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="forms.selected" value="{{value}}" ng-click="radioCheckUncheck($event)">
```

Controller

```
  let lastChecked = null
  $scope.radioCheckUncheck = function (event) {
    if (event.target.value === lastChecked) {
      delete $scope.forms.selected
      lastChecked = null
    } else {
      lastChecked = event.target.value
    }
  }
```

It's similar to the above solution, but maintains its own copy of the previous selection.

Comment: Great Works fine Angular 1.3+

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the following code:

```
ng-dblclick = "{{model}} = '' "
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to add:

```
ng-dblclick = "checked = null"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do using below.
set an attribute.

```
public selectedMoiProfile : boolean  = false;

<input type="radio" 
       name="selectMoi"
       [checked]="selectedProfile"
       [value]="selectedProfile"
       (click)="onSelect(moiProfile)"
       class="selectMoi">


 onSelect(p: profile) {
     p.selectedProfile= p.selectedProfile? false : true;
 }
```