# set default value of false to radio button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set the value of radio button to false. Only when clicked it should be set to true. This is my code:

```
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="ERRORS">ERRORS<br>
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="OCCURRENCES">OCCURRENCES<br>
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-value="true" ng-model="STATUS">STATUS<br>

 <div>
   Selected Data Value:
   Selected Data<br>
    ERRORS: {{ ERRORS }}<br>
    OCCURRENCES: {{OCCURRENCES }}<br>
    STATUS: {{ STATUS }}<br>
  </div>
```

However i am getting the value as "true" if radio button selected and empty when it is not selected.

Comment: Set the initial value in your controller or use ng-init?

Comment: I believe you will find what you are looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443018/angularjs-is-it-possible-to-deselect-html-radio-input-by-click

Comment: @yeouuu, i tried that but did not work. i set ng-init="false" for each radio button

Comment: try ng-init="ERRORS=false" and so on

Comment: @yeouuu, thanks its working

Comment: I strongly disagree with using an excessive code in your template.
Look at Angular documentation regarding `ng-init`:
"This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use **controllers** rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope."

Comment: @AranS I agree, I would do it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an old javascript trick - an empty string is perceived is a false boolean.

Comment: can u explain how to do that in angular? should i set ng-init=" "

Comment: Currently, when your app is up, you have three radio buttons that are unchecked. Their value is empty, when they are clicked they their value is true. So you have three variables in your controller (`ERRORS`, `OCCURENCES` and `STATUS`. Am I correct this far?

Comment: yes, so should i reset the value to false when unchecking? Is there not any attribute which sets the value to false like in checkbox like ng-true-value and ng-false-value

Comment: no need for that. Your variables are false as they are empty strings.

Comment: yes, in controller we can do that, i was looking whether it can be done in any declarative way.

Comment: Taken from MDN Javascript documentation:
"If value is omitted or is 0, -0, null, false, NaN, undefined, or the empty string (""), the object has an initial value of false. All other values, including any object or the string "false", create an object with an initial value of true."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113042/discussion-between-arans-and-user2010243).

Comment: Thank you very much AranS, we can set it to false declaratively. @yeouuu has suggested the ng-init above

Comment: yes AranS, controllers are the best way. i was just looking for declarative approach as in checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ng-init or in your controller(I recommend this way):

Examples:

```
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-init="ERRORS= false" 
    ng-value="true" ng-model="ERRORS">ERRORS<br>
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-init="OCCURRENCES= false" 
    ng-value="true" ng-model="OCCURRENCES">OCCURRENCES<br>
<input type="radio" name="data" ng-init="STATUS= false" 
    ng-value="true" ng-model="STATUS">STATUS<br>
```

Or you could initialize the values inside your controller:

```
$scope.ERRORS = false;
...
```